# How to call getResource() for external URL in JavaFX 2

Tags: netbeans, javafx-2

I want to load an image that exists outside the application directory for example :

**OK** : `url = Person.class.getResource("user_info.png").toString();`

**KO** : `url = Person.class.getResource("C:/images/user_info.png").toString();`

My situation is that : I have a lot of images (>1000) that the application will need when running, and I want to create a directory that contains all images, then access to it from the app.

Configuration : Netbeans 7.2, JavaFX 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for local paths use `file:/` prefix, for web you can just use URLs:

```
    Image image = new Image("file:/c:/images/user_info.png");
```